# wordpress interpreting style.css differently?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I just went and installed my wordpress theme and it's doing some strange things. The problem is with the menu. Here's how it should look like (ignore the fact that it's not in English)

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/br9LwwLy/

The actual wp site: http://tasmaniandevilz.com/mima/

As you can see, the bottom border (underline) is not animated and there is a tiny gap under each menu item that is not the actual link - when I hover over that spot, the sub-menu disappears. Strangely enough, this is only the problem in Chrome.
I have no clue what's going on. The links are dynamically taken from the pages. Here's the header code.

```
<div class='container'>
<header class='clearfix'>
<a href='<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>'><h1>Misia Máriina</h1></a>
<nav>
<ul>
<li>
<a class='bordermenu'><?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&depth=2&exclude=359,368,441,439,443,516&title_li='); ?></a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
<img class='sep' src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/sep.png" />
</div>
```

There is one more error. The special characters are encoded strangely on the home page. 
[s16.postimg.org/5ohsvb0hh/image.jpg](http://s16.postimg.org/dv9smvqk5/image.jpg)

It's weird that when you click on some of the links, it works alright.

[s16.postimg.org/5ohsvb0hh/image.jpg](http://s16.postimg.org/5ohsvb0hh/image.jpg)

I am guessing there's some problem in the mysql database encoding? But why is it happening only on the home page?

Answer (score 0):

On your site, the links `<a>` does not have class `.bordermenu`

About encoding: [**LINK 1**](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/utf-8-encoding-problem) [**LINK 2**](https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-fix-the-character-encoding-problem-in-wordpress-1480) [**LINK 3**](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/encoding-problems)

**UPDATE:**
Your `<a>` still don't have `.bordermenu` class.
Check the image:
[image]
And when I'm adding that class manually in dev. tools it works fine:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. But that doesn't help at all. I updated the site code, you can have a look yourself.

Comment: you are right. If you look, WP kind of creates additional list items.. if you unwrap the li above (the 'original one', it's empty but it has that bordermenu class. 
http://s9.postimg.org/4qp8hbub3/image.png
Here's the code from header.php again:
http://s9.postimg.org/s675moe27/image.png
Thanks for help Mihey.

Comment: I would suggest you to create another question about problems in generating menu.